# After reading and writing, the same data is returned from the stream с++

Tags: c++, stl, stream, visual-c++-2019

I wanted to implement the idea of working with a file as an array. Here is a piece of code. After the next write, the same data is returned from the stream. If I do a flush after write data, everything will be fine. Tell me why you need a flash here and can you do without it?

```
std::fstream _fs;
_fs.open("temp.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out |ios::trunc);
std::vector<double> vec(ELEMENT_SIZE);
std::streamoff _current_putpos = 0;
std::streamoff _end_pos = 0;
size_t size = ELEMENT_SIZE * sizeof(double);
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        vec[j] = (double)i;
    
    _fs.write((const char*)vec.data(), size);
    _end_pos += ELEMENT_SIZE * sizeof(double);
    _current_putpos = _end_pos;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    //get at, after read at index 2 return always {1,1,1,1....} 

    std::streamoff sizeoffset = static_cast<std::streamoff>(i * size);
    std::streamoff seek = sizeoffset - _current_putpos;
    if (seek != static_cast<std::streamoff>(0))
        _fs.seekg(seek, std::ios::cur);

    memset(vec.data(), -1, size);
    _fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vec.data()), size);
    _current_putpos = _current_putpos + seek + static_cast<std::streamoff>(size);
    //set at
    for (size_t j = 5; j < 10; j++)
        vec[j] = (double)j;

    sizeoffset = static_cast<std::streamoff>(i * size);
    seek = sizeoffset - _current_putpos;
    if (seek != static_cast<std::streamoff>(0))
        _fs.seekp(seek, std::ios::cur);
    
    _fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vec.data()), size);
    _current_putpos = _current_putpos + seek + static_cast<std::streamoff>(size);
}
```

Comment: You are required to do a flush or positioning operation when switching from writing to reading. You are also required to do a positioning operation when switching from reading to writing. This is the case in C, I believe it's also the case with C++ streams as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have to do a flash? If so, why? In this example, after the set, you will have to call a flush every time, and I would not want that.

Comment: You have to do a flush because that what the API says you have to do. But you only have to do a flush when you switch from writing to reading. So you don't have to do a flush after **every** set. But the bottom line is that you can't treat a file exactly the same as an array.